# Add static block in product detail page only for certain categories

Tags: magento

I want to add a static block in Product detail page for category 4. I did like this:

```
$catid = $this->helper('catalog/data')->getProduct()->getCategoryIds();
?>
<?php $blockID = "free_shipping_" + $catid ?>
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId($blockID)->toHtml()  
?>
```

and then in admin I created a static block with URL and blocktitle `free_shipping_4`.
(4  in free_shipping_4 stands for category 4).

I get the error :

> Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in C:\wamp\www\mydomain\app\design\frontend\default\mytheme\template\catalog\product\view.phtml on line 140

Comment: What does line 140 look like?

Comment: `$this->helper('catalog/data')->getProduct()->getCategoryIds();` returns an array containing the IDs of all the categories to which the current product is associated, not a single ID, so `"free_shipping_" + $catid` can't work (I guess this is line 140).

Comment: I am using my own theme. Initially line 40 was                        <?php $blockID = "product-view-static-links_" .$catid; ?>  But now I found out $catid is array. So with $catid[1] it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

$catid = $this->helper('catalog/data')->getProduct()->getCategoryIds();
    ?>
    
    getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId($blockID)->toHtml() ?>

```
$catid will contain array of id product is associated with.
```

I think one way is to create an product attribute and that will contain category id need to show and then you can retrieve product attribute.

```
<?php $blockID = "free_shipping_" + $productattributevalue ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you are right. I found out that now that $catid is an array. So I used
$catid[1] to get the catalog ID. So my code looks like this

```
<?php $blockID = "free_shipping_" . $catid[1]?>
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId($blockID)->toHtml();
```

To find the catalog id I am interested to use in the Static block name (free_shipping_4) I used the following code

```
 SELECT entity_id AS categoryID, value AS categoryName
    FROM catalog_category_entity_varchar
    WHERE attribute_id =4
    LIMIT 0 , 30
```

It is solved now. Although there must be a better and easier way to do it.